# Screen Orientation in portrait mode

Tags: android, android-layout, android-orientation, google-chrome-os

The recent version of Android Studio (Version 3.6) gives an error if the Screen Orientation set in the portrait mode

[image]

Displaying message `Expecting android:screenOrientation="unspecified" or "fullSensor".`

and showing this inspection like this,

[image]

It's not creating any problem though but I want to remove this error line.

Any solutions?

Comment: it's much better to paste code with formatting instead of images

Answer (score 1):

It's displayed to inform you that it's not advisable to restrict the orientation especially when it comes to devices which are equipped with bigger screens. If it is bothering you and want to get rid of it, you can always deactivate it under Editor/Inspections - `Activity is locked to an orientation`.

If you're lazy as I am (or smart) quickly press the left Shift on your keyboard two times - edit field should pop up - and type the phrase you're looking for, in this case `Activity is locked to an orientation` - it will take you straight to it.